# Android Textview cuts off from right side of screen

Tags: android, rotation, textview

I have a rotated textview with Hello text. When textview is dragged to right side of screen textview is cutting from right side? Due to single Line set to true text is not cut off, but textview with magenta color is cut off. Same is case for bottom side. For left and top side of screen it is not cutting off.

[image]

```
parentLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
parentLayout.setId(6);

LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
parentLayout.setLayoutParams(params);
layout.addView(parentLayout);           

objTextView = new TextView(this);
objTextView.setId(5);
objTextView.setText("Hello"); 
objTextView.setTextSize(60);
objTextView.setMaxLines(1);
objTextView.setSingleLine(true);
objTextView.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
objTextView.setBackgroundColor(Color.MAGENTA);

params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
parentLayout.addView(objTextView,params);

parentLayout.setOnTouchListener(MyOnTouchListener); 

OnTouchListener MyOnTouchListener = new OnTouchListener(){
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
switch (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {

// When single finger is down.
case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:


//Start is the point from where we start moving/draging/scaling.
if(view instanceof LinearLayout)
{
    start.set(event.getX() - rlLayoutParamsCanvas.leftMargin, event.getY() - rlLayoutParamsCanvas.topMargin);
}

Log.d(TAG, "mode=DRAG");
mode = DRAG;
break;

 //When single finger is up.
 case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:

//When second finger is up.
case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:

break;

//When 2 fingers are down.
case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN:

    if(view instanceof LinearLayout){
        fTextViewSize = objTextView.getTextSize();
}
break;

//When fingers move.
case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
if (mode == DRAG) // drag view
{

    if(view instanceof LinearLayout) 
    {   
        rlLayoutParamsCanvas.leftMargin =  (int) (event.getX() - start.x);
        rlLayoutParamsCanvas.topMargin = (int) (event.getY() - start.y);
        objTextView.setLayoutParams(rlLayoutParamsCanvas);
    }
}

//When two fingers are down the mode = zoom, means we can now zoom and rotate as well
else if (mode == ZOOM && event.getPointerCount() == 2) {
    float newDist = CommonMethods.spacing(event);


        if (view instanceof LinearLayout) 
        {   
            objTextView.setTextSize(scale * fTextViewSize);
        }


    //Rotate watermark/textview.
    if (lastEvent != null) 
    {
        //Calculate rotation
        newRotation = CommonMethods.rotation(event);
        float rotation = newRotation - fingersDownRot;

        if (view instanceof LinearLayout)
        {
            objTextView.setRotation(SetRotation(rotation));
        } 

    }
}
break;
}
```

Update Image.
[image]

Comment: Your code is incomplete. Please post the full code so I can try your example. What is parentLayout.setOnTouchListener(MyOnTouchListener); ?

Comment: @userM1433372: Code is edited, kindly check. On parent layout we can drag drop translate and scale textview.

Comment: Still doesn't compile. Please upload file java file.

Comment: @userM1433372: You cannot compile java file, because this is in a big project. Kindly check from code i have provided with question.

Comment: @FarrakhJaved does it happened upon zooming or translating?

Comment: @Rod_Algonquin: On both.

Comment: @userM1433372: Can i have you email ID, I will send you complete project.

Comment: @FarrakhJaved use github.

Comment: @FarrakhJaved post the rlLayoutParamsCanvas where you initialized it

Comment: @Rod_Algonquin: rlLayoutParamsCanvas = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) objTextView.getLayoutParams();

Comment: Hello Javed, i want to perform this task but i cant do so please guide me for implement this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Upon debugging and simulating with the same code that you have the problem is this code:

```
rlLayoutParamsCanvas.leftMargin =  (int) (event.getX() - start.x);
rlLayoutParamsCanvas.topMargin = (int) (event.getY() - start.y);
objTextView.setLayoutParams(rlLayoutParamsCanvas);
```

Now you are saying that set the margin of it and if it is more than the width of then screen the cut off some of it, you can try it with a regular view by setting its margin more than its parent it will differently cut off parts of it.

**solution:**

instead of using the `layoutparams` just to move your textview use its `setX` and `setY` to change **locations** on the screen

**sample:**

```
if (mode == DRAG) // drag view
{

   if(view instanceof LinearLayout) 
   {   
       objTextView.setY((int) (event.getY() - start.y));
       objTextView.setX((int) (event.getX() - start.x));
   }
}
```

Comment: If we rotate textview within screen bounds and than drag it is working, but if Textview is out of bound and we start zooming than getting same issue of cutting off.

Comment: @FarrakhJaved at least we solve one of the problem, now post the result image what it looks like

Comment: @FarrakhJaved it is normal to me the image what is the problem?.

Comment: Now if we zoom where it now we got again that issue. Can you check why is that?

Comment: @FarrakhJaved That is because the width of the textView is greater than the screen width, just make a flag each time you zoom that check textViews width

Comment: Sorry did not get you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58936/discussion-between-rod-algonquin-and-farrakh-javed).

Comment: @FarrakhJaved you can convert the the textView to imageView and use that to zoom.

Comment: That is not the good solution for this scenario because when we zoom text size gets blur.

Comment: @FarrakhJaved then you have no choice but to limit your textView width

Comment: Yes I'm agree with you.